# get data value on bootstrap carousel slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is a sample version of bootstrap carousel...

I want to get the item from indicators that calls the slide...

I have added a new data-value in the indicators, but how to catch on slid.bs.carousel?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="A" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="B" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="C" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Chania">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

here...

```
<script>
  $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    alert(?? data-value ??);
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your indicator values in **slid.bs.carousel** event handler selecting the active **li**:

```
$('#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li.active')
```

```js
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var ele = $('#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li.active');
    console.log('target: ' + ele.data('target') + 
                ' value: ' + ele.data('value') + 
                ' slide-to: ' + ele.data('slideTo'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="A" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="B" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="C" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=1" alt="Chania">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=2" alt="Chicago">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Chicago</h3>
                <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=3" alt="New York">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>New York</h3>
                <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```